# In Java, how to make each element in an array a button?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

For my CS project, I'm making a multiple choice quiz. Each quiz has a question and four possible answers. The right answer is saved as a String. All the wrong answers are saved in an array of Strings. I want to make a button for each of those. But I don't want the correct answer to always be in the same position, so I want to randomly place it. After I randomly place it, I don't know how to make buttons for the array of strings. Help!

`
    public Display(){

```
    answer1 = new JButton("1");
    answer2 = new JButton("2");
    answer3 = new JButton("3");
    answer4 = new JButton("");
    question = new JLabel ("question?");
}

public Display(String question1, String [] answers, String correct, String pictureName){
    //create a panel to hold buttons

    SimplePicture background = new SimplePicture(pictureName);
    JLabel picture = background.getJLabel();

    question = new JLabel(question1);

    //assign answers to buttons

    //generate a random number to determine where correct goes
    int index = (int)(Math.random()*4);

    //place correct answer in a certain button
    if (index == 0){
        answer1 = new JButton(correct);
    }
    else if (index == 1){
        answer2 = new JButton(correct);
    }
    else if (index == 2){
        answer3 = new JButton(correct);
    }
    else if (index == 3){
        answer4 = new JButton(correct);
    }

    //fill other spots with answers
    for (int i=0; i < answers.length; i++){
        this is where I need help

        }
    }`
```

Comment: Maybe some sort of visual would help. I am not understanding your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Now with the answer to your question:

Since you know beforehand how many Buttons there are you can simply use an array.

```
JButton[] buttons;

buttons = new JButton[4] // or new JButton[answers.length] if you ever 
                         // want to increase the amount of answers.

//assign answers to buttons

//generate a random number to determine where correct goes
int index = (int)(Math.random() * 4);

//put the correct answer to the random button:
buttons[index] = new JButton(correct)

//fill other spots with answers
for (int i = 1; i <= answers.length; i++) {
    buttons[(index + i) % answers.length] = new JButton(answers[i - 1]);
}
```

So what this does in case you dont know the `%` is the modulus operator in java. So if `(index + i)` ever goes above 3 (presuming `answers.length` is 3) it will become 0 again so you won't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting an error message with List. It says that List isn't generic and it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JButton>. What should I do?

Comment: Hmm make sure you have the correct imports: I'll add them to the answer above

Comment: @darknessofshadows sorry I'm a complete idiot, I didn't read your question right.. I will change my answer.